# class swaping in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to change `class` on click on a tag.

The requirement is when we click on tag whichever div has `active` should replace with `second` and then inside next li div which has class name `second` should replace with `active`. i made small function but it is not working properly.

```
<div class="wrap">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="first">
                <div class="second"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="first">
                <div class="active"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="first">
                <div class="second"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" id="next">Next</a>
</div>

$(function(){
    $('#next').click(function (){
        $('ul').find('li').each(function (){
            if($(this).find('div').hasClass('active')){
                $(this).removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('second');  
                $(this).next().closest('div').next().attr('class','active');
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: replace next after closest('div') with closest('div'). Ex: closest('div').closest('div') or closest('div div')

Comment: your `$(this).removeClass('active');` refers to li and not the div which has active class. Replace it with `$(this).find('div').removeClass('active');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$('#next').click(function (){
    $active = $('.active');

    $active.toggleClass('active second');
    $active.closest('li').next().find('.second').toggleClass('second active');
});
```

[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CgDS6/6/)

If you want to start over at the first li after reaching the bottom, this should work for you:

```
var $firstSecond = $('.second').eq(0);

$('#next').click(function (){
    var $active = $('.active');
    var $nextSecond = $active.closest('li').next().find('.second');

    $active.toggleClass('active second');

    if($nextSecond.size() != 0)
        $nextSecond.toggleClass('second active');
    else
        $firstSecond.toggleClass('second active');
});
```

[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CgDS6/8/)

Comment: `.toggleClass('active second')` is a shortcut on that one line.

Comment: Also, it falls off and doesn't rotate back to start.

Comment: Did the OP specify that as the desired goal? Thanks for the toggleClass tip.

Comment: Well, I guess the current demo makes perfect sense: Go one, disappear.

Comment: I added a version where it starts over as well.

Comment: You've got global variables (`$active = ` on first line), re-queries in the global scope, and you don't have to test for `.html()` which can be slow; use `.size()`. The first two, though, should probably be avoided if possible (and it is here).

Comment: The $active needs to requery every time because it is not always the same object in the dom right? Although, I will change the html to size though.

Comment: Take a look at my answer; because the `.wrap` isn't really a series, I changed it to an `id` and cache it to work on. `$('.className')` is really slow, too. I also show how to use `$(this)` with the `.next` toggle element if it is a series.

Answer (score 1):

I made a slight change to your markup:

```
<div id="wrap">
```

That's an `id`. This allows me to cache it's reference in a closure as pointing to a specific element. If you are actually using that in a series and not as an `id`, the following would be different. But I thought I would show you how this would work with caching and traversing.

```
$(function(){
    var $ul = $('#wrap ul');

    $('#next').click(function (){
        var $active = $ul.find('.active'),
            $new = $active.parents('li').next();

        $active.toggleClass('active second');

        if ($new.size() < 1) {
            $new = $active.parents('li').siblings().first();
        }

        $new.find('.second').toggleClass('second active');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/y29uJ/

So if you were to run a series of these...

```
$(function(){
    $('.next').click(function (){
        var $active = $(this).parent().find('.active'),
            $new = $active.parents('li').next();

        $active.toggleClass('active second');

        if ($new.size() < 1) {
            $new = $active.parents('li').siblings().first();
        }

        $new.find('.second').toggleClass('second active');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/y29uJ/5

Answer (score 0):

`toggleClass` is what you are looking for in jQuery [documentation/examples](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Comment: Yes you could replace removeClass and add class with toggle, but only if the class is single. Otherwise you will replace the entire contents of class.

Comment: Hi Astro, good idea. I was actually going to do it the hard way ;) For completeness in StackOverflow answers, consider making an [edit] to your answer to include an example that applies to the problem. This gives your answer some context and will help others who visit this page for years to come. Good luck!